# Email won't send

Tags: linux, email, exim, email-bounces, dkim

```
2013-01-18 10:33:04 cwd=/home/USER/public_html/clients 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
2013-01-18 10:33:04 1TwDwG-00023y-Ks <= USER@host.mydomain.com U=USER P=local S=3993 id=3e7cefe5079a84f36d64c08f99900d95@mydomain.com T="[Ticket ID: 787676] test" for EMAILUSER@hotmail.com 
2013-01-18 10:33:04 cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1TwDwG-00023y-Ks
2013-01-18 10:33:04 1TwDwG-00023y-Ks SMTP connection outbound 1358523184 1TwDwG-00023y-Ks mydomain.com EMAILUSER@hotmail.com
2013-01-18 10:33:05 1TwDwG-00023y-Ks ** EMAILUSER@hotmail.com R=lookuphost  T=remote_smtp: SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<USER@nhost.mydomain.com> SIZE=5115: host mx2.hotmail.com [65.55.37.72]: 550 SC-001 (COL0-MC1-F11) Unfortunately, messages from weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
```

What is wrong with hotmail? IP is not in any blacklists but hotmail won't send my emails...

I have SPF enabled in my domain.

How do I enable DKIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The URL that Hotmail gave you](http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors) said, in relevant part:

> 550 SC-001
>   Mail rejected by Hotmail for policy reasons. Reasons for rejection may
>   be related to content with spam-like characteristics or IP/domain
>   reputation. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your
>   Email/Internet Service Provider for help.

Since you aren't on any blacklists that I can find, and [your Sender Score is 100](https://www.senderscore.org/lookup.php?lookup=198.23.157.180&ipLookup=Go), the next place to look is at the characteristics of the messages you are sending.

Again, as the URL that Hotmail gave you said, after you've resolved all of your issues, if you *still* can't deliver mail, you can [submit a support request](https://support.msn.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl2&ct=eformts).

Answer (score 2):

Hotmail have their own blocklists and as the log message points out - other ips - from the same block as yours (i.e. other customers of your isp) are in block lists.

Hotmail is blocking you because of this.

Unless you are wanting a learning experience or are simply masochistic, get someone who manages large quantities of mail to manage yours. It can be a full time job just meeting their requirements.

Comment: Well this is a private server, just client invoices, nothing major. IP is not even in any blacklists.

Comment: your server doesn't have to be in the blacklist... another server in the same block being blacklisted is enough to block you. This holds even if the other server has nothing to do with you. The fact that they are both on the same block is enough...

Comment: Spammers are lame. Hotmail's just protective.

Answer (score 0):

You could use another smart host. If you don't need to send so many emails it's possible to configure your server to send through gmail or another provider.
http://rs20.mine.nu/w/2011/07/gmail-as-relay-host-in-postfix/
Make sure you really don't send thousands of mails because other smart hosts may have their own limitations and they may slow down or even stop your delivery if you are sending too much.

Comment: can this be done with exim too?

Comment: sure it can, every mail server can be configured to send through another host: http://islandlinux.org/howto/configure-exim-use-gmail-smtp-server